# systemjs loader does not include .js while loading angular internal script files by import

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs

In my angular2 application I am trying to load typescript compiled javascript rom different server. when when I try to load the javascript file without .js extension it makes a rest call without .js extension and gives 404 error.

```
error
VM9887:1274 GET http://localhost:9099/OfferFinder7oct/app/app.module 404 (Not Found)

in detail the error is the systemjs is trying to load http://localhost:3000/app/app.module as "./app.module" but unable to reach http://localhost:3000/app/main.js




System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });

//system.config.js
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `defaultExtension: 'js'` to your configuration main section. Your configuration does not understand default extension for the file without any extension.

New configuration would look like this

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
```

Comment: configuration main section of what? what file, what path?

Comment: Add this into the systemjs configuration.